# Error creating bean with name 'shelfRepository' defined in goodReadClone.WebProject.repository.ShelfRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, beancreationexception

I'm also new to spring boot and the application seems to throw an error at compilation. While my classes look properly anotated and almost the same as in example given by the teacher

**Code of entity:**

```
package goodReadClone.WebProject.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Shelf implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private boolean primary;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ShelfInstance shelfInstance;
}
```

I have almost completely copied example code adding word for word requirements from document file
**code of Repository:**

```
package goodReadClone.WebProject.repository;

import goodReadClone.WebProject.entity.Shelf;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ShelfRepository extends JpaRepository<Shelf, Long>{
}
```

**Full stack trace:**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-19T11:13:41.311+02:00 ERROR 25992 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shelfRepository' defined in goodReadClone.WebProject.repository.ShelfRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on WebProjectApplication: Not a managed type: class goodReadClone.WebProject.entity.Shelf
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at goodReadClone.WebProject.WebProjectApplication.main(WebProjectApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class goodReadClone.WebProject.entity.Shelf
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I added @EnableJpaRepositories and @EntityScan as internet suggested but it still doesn't work
**Main application file:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "goodReadClone.WebProject.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "goodReadClone.WebProject.entity")
public class WebProjectApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Similar question has been asked but not answered: [Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in com.example.jpa.repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596596/error-creating-bean-with-name-userrepo-defined-in-com-example-jpa-repository)

Comment: Using Spring Boot 3 requires Jakarta Persistence (`jakarta.persistence` package not `javax.persistence`). Remove the dependency that pulls in that dependency and fix the imports and remove `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`.